# Trying to change a embed footer text with a for loop

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, footer

```
for footer in embed_dict["footer"]:
    footer["text"] = "new text"
embed_new = discord.Embed.from_dict(embed_dict)
await messageraids.edit(embed=raidedit1embed)
```

I get the error:

> ```
> footer["text"] = "new text"
> TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
> ```

Anyone know how to fix this

Comment: Have you looked this error up? You're trying to assign to a string, which isn't allowed in Python since strings are immutable. What exactly is in `embed_dict["footer"]` that you're iterating over?

Comment: @MihaiChelaru it has`{'text': '0/10 Total'}`
And it's the 0/10 Total i want to change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment clarifying that `embed_dict["footer"]` contains `{'text': '0/10 Total'}`, your problem is you're iterating over that value in the line:

```py
for footer in embed_dict["footer"]:
```

Doing so iterates over the keys of that dictionary, so `footer` has a value of `'text'`, and you're doing `footer["text"] = "new text"`, which you can't do on a string. You should simply do:

```py
embed_dict["footer"]["text"] = "new text"
```